# I wanna load results.html when I put vote button

Tags: python, django

I am making a web site by seeing Django tutorial.
I wanna load results.html when I put vote button is in detail.html ,but now index.html is loaded.detail.html is

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block contents %}

<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<!--{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}-->

<form action="{% url 'polls:poll_vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I put vote button is this code `<input type="submit" value="Vote" />`,
I wanna show results.html .
views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.contrib import messages



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })


def vote(request,pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'poll/detail.html',{
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return redirect('poll_results', pk)
    # pass

def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

class FormTest(FormView):
   form_class = MyForm
   template_name = 'polls/form.html'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('polls:index')
form_test = FormTest.as_view()

class Detail(SingleObjectMixin,FormView):
    model = Question
    form_class = VoteForm
    context_object_name = 'question'
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['question'] = self.object
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.vote()
        choice = form.cleaned_data['choice']
        messages.success(self.request,'"%s"に投票しました' % choice)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return resolve_url('polls:results',self.kwargs['pk'])

detail = Detail.as_view()
```

I think `def vote(request,pk)` is read,so `return redirect('poll_results', pk)` is also read and results.html is load.But my ideal flow is not realized.Was I wrong to write directory?
Directory is
[image: directory]

How can I fix this?`return redirect('polls_results', pk)` did not work.

Now I received one answer,
vote method in views.py is

```
def vote(request,pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'poll/detail.html',{
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return redirect(reverse('polls_results'), pk=pk)
```

but same error happens.
urls.py in polls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name="polls"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='poll_detail'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/vote$', views.vote, name='poll_vote'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/results$', views.results, name='poll_results'),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^form$', views.form_test),
]
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's not possible to tell what's wrong here. You should include your `urls.py`, and don't include view functions that are not relevant.

Comment: @HåkenLid sorry,I include my urls.py,if u know something please tell me.

Comment: Also, post the error traceback. Saying it did not work, does not seem to help identify the issue.

Comment: @SachinKukreja nothing error happens.always not base.html but index.html is shown when i put vote button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using [namespaced urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).

In that case, you should use the namespace prefix whenever you use `reverse`, `redirect` or `{% url %}`.

```
return redirect('polls:polls_results', pk=pk)
```

Comment: I wrote return redirect(reverse('polls:poll_results'), pk=pk),but NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/vote
Reverse for 'poll_results' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<pk>\\d+)/results$'] error happens.

Comment: When I use return redirect('polls:polls_results' pk=pk) ,syntax error happens.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry. I had a typo. There should be a `,` between the arguments in the function call. I've edited my answer to fix that syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reverse` or write the correct path in `redirect` method.

**Example**:

```
 from django.urls import reverse

 def the_view(request):
     # change here
     return redirect(reverse('poll_results'), pk=pk)
     # or
     return redirect('results_url', pk=pk)
```

EDIT: Based on your urlpatterns, it seems that you're passing the wrong name in the `reverse` method, `polls_results`, where as you've defined it to be as `poll_results`.

You haven't removed the `redirect` to `index` statement in `else` part of the code in `vote` method.

```
def vote(request, pk):
    # your code
    else:
        # save to model
        # remove redirect statement here
    return redirect(reverse('poll_results'), pk=pk)
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: I updated my question,if I misunderstood ur answer,please tell me.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried ur codes,but still index.html is shown...How can i do it?

Comment: You didn't remove the `return redirect('index')` statement from the else part of the code in vote method.

Comment: I deleted the redirect to index statement in else part ,but new error happens.It said ,NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/vote
Reverse for 'poll_results' not found. 'poll_results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: how can I fix this?